# Create html bookmarklet instead of javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, bookmarklet

Is there a way to create a bookmarklet without javascript? Maybe with HTML? Javascript bookmarklets won't work in chrome new tabs. What it does is it creates a javascript link to my website. Here's the current javascript bookmarklet:

```
javascript:(function () {var script=document.createElement('script');script.src='https://MY.SITE/URL'; document.body.appendChild(script)})();
```

Is there a way to do it with `data/html`? Thanks in advance!

Comment: No, not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can encode an HTML document in [a `data:` scheme URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs) and bookmark that (although it wouldn't be a bookmarklet as they are JS by definition).